# Python Iterate through files, Search for certain string, if found copy rest of the lines and consolidate to a combined file

Tags: python

I have a folder contains 500 text files.
Python Iterate through files Search for certain string if found copy and consolidate to a combined file as "Output.txt".
The string we are looking for in each of the file in the directory

```
import os

searchquery = 'No' #string we are looking for in each of the file in the directory
def my_function(fname):
    Output=[]
    with fname as f1:
      with Output as f2:

        Lines = f1.readlines()

        try:
          i = Lines.index(searchquery)
          for iline in range(i+1, i+18): # we need to copy rest of the 18 or less line after 'No' is found
            f2.write(Lines[iline])
        except:
          print(" ")
    return Output

for filename in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\Tox\\tcm2'):
    M1=open(filename)
    M2=my_function(M1)
    opened_file = open(Output.txt, 'a')
    opened_file.write("%r\n" % M1)
    opened_file.close()
```

I am seeing the following error

```
    with Output as f2:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: What is the point of `with fname as f1` and `with Output as f2`?  What do you expect those to do?

Comment: Thank you so much. I also think they are not necessary. As I have an external for loop to iterate through the files.

Comment: Sir but how do I search for specific string please look at the text files ..filebin.net/03o53ixhjitshsgb/tcm2.zip?t=savks9cu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot do `with Output as f2` , because `Output` is a list and it doesn't support that, and gives you `AttributeError: __enter__` , another problem is the line where you did `f2.write()` again you cannot write to a list, use `append()` instead.

Here is the full working code, i tested it :

```
import os
searchquery = 'No'
path = 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\Tox\\tcm2\\'

def my_function(fname):
    Output=[]           
    Lines = fname.readlines()   
    found = False 
    for line in Lines :
        if (found == True):
            Output.append(line)
        if line.startswith(searchquery):
            found = True
    return Output

opened_file = open('Output.txt', 'a')
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    M1=open(path+filename)
    result=my_function(M1)        
    for e in result:
        opened_file.write(e)        
    M1.close()
opened_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much but still facing error with this section     "opened_file = open(Output.txt, 'a')
    opened_file.write("%r\n" % M1)
    opened_file.close()"    ERROR      opened_file = open(Output.txt, 'a')
NameError: name 'Output' is not defined

Comment: take a look at my edited answer, hope that fixes all your problems, you have many of them man xD

Comment: Thanks again but still same problem on the line................................. "opened_file = open(Output.txt, 'a')"      ...................Error.................. NameError: name 'Output' is not defined

Comment: `opened_file = open('Output.txt', 'a')` and I'm here till your code works man, and you are welcome :)

Comment: The code runs but the output file is empty. the few files that I am searching through ...... from tcm2 folder  I have uploaded.to ....https://filebin.net/03o53ixhjitshsgb/tcm2.zip?t=savks9cu

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using a cmd line, go to the directory and run:

```
grep no -A18 * | egrep -v "no|--" > output.txt
```

In case you do not have egrep:

```
grep no -A18 * | grep -v no | grep -v "--" > output.txt
```

Comment: Sorry but what is this "|" i don't set it on my keyboard.  Are those for windows? I am not in Linux... It shows ERROR.......................'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: powershell has grep for sure, maybe not egrep

Comment: Error ......grep : The term 'grep' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: hmmm, I have grep in my work windows powershell, maybe my company installs it for us.

Comment: https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-grep-equivalent-cmd-powershell/